# SCNRender scene with animated objects

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, scenekit

I have **SCNScene** with animated objects (.*dae* files) and also I have **SCNRender** initialized with **openGLContext**.
When I set my animated scene to this render I don't see animation, but when I set my animated scene to **SCNView**, I see animations.

how I set Render:

```
self.renderer = [SCNRenderer rendererWithContext:_openGLContext options:nil];
self.renderer.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
self.renderer.playing = YES;
self.renderer.scene = myAnimatedScene;
```

I understand that OpenGL can only draw objects, it doesn't know anything about animation settings in my *.dae* file

Can somebody explain me how I can draw animated scene using **SCNRender** initialized with **openGLContext**?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that when calling the following function:

```
renderer.render(atTime: time, viewport: viewport,
                commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                passDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
```

the *time* parameter is really important. Before I just left it with zero and there were no animations. If you set it with CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), it seems that you can only get one animation (I've just tested it. My game hero has a shooting action as well as a walking one, and by setting *atTime* with CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), only the walking one appears.)

However, our situations are a little bit different. In my case, I also have a SCNView that renders the hero's perspective. So in order to run all the animations, I created a globe variable:

```
var globeTime:TimeInterval = 0
```

And saved the current time in the SCNView's renderer function:

```
func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
              updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    globeTime = time
    //...
}
```

And finally passed it to my SCNRender.

```
//...
renderer.render(atTime: globeTime, viewport: viewport,
                commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                passDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
```

This solved my problem perfectly.